# Remove user account privledges from db table

Tags: mysql, privileges

Hi how to delete the database privileges for a user? I don't want to delete the user just to delete the privileges...

Actually, we've set up a cron to create new database daily and we give access privileges to a user. We dropped the old db when new db created but it is not deleting the privileges given to the db.

Today when i look at the db table, it showing 1000 entries. I want to delete all the old database privileges, how to do this without deleting the user

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL flavors have a REVOKE command. It mostly depends on what you're using. For example, you can look at the code [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html) for MySQL 5.0 or [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177573.aspx) for Transact-SQL used in Access databases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use REVOKE command. For example:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.*;
```

Comment: This will remove all privileges on all the database, right? I want to remove privileges on particular database....

Comment: @VinodkumarSaravana , i have edited my answer, now the privileges on 'db' will only be deleted